# How can I reduce the webpack bundle size for a Vue.js / Nuxt.js project incorporating AWS SDK?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, aws-sdk, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

## Summary:

I have created projects, with Vue.js and Nuxt.js, where I have installed aws-amplify (which automatically installs aws-sdk) in order that I can implement authentication with AWS Cognito.

In both cases, this works very nicely, but the problems come when I build production versions.

In both cases, I end up with massive bundle sizes which (thanks to webpack-bundle-analyzer) I can immediately see are caused by the aws-sdk  which appears to contain code to implement every AWS service, under the sun, despite the fact that I am only importing AWS Cognito's: "Auth" (import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify')

I have tried creating a custom AWS SDK for JavaScript, which only includes the service: AWS.CognitoIdentity, but despite incorporating that (presumably incorrectly), I still end up with the same bundle size (and aws-sdk files) when I build the projects.

As I say, this is happening in both Nuxt and Vue project, but in order to simplify this, I for now just want to find the solution to a very basic sample project created with Vue.

I think I must be doing something dumb, but I can't work out what that is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a basic Vue.js project with defaults. Run: `vue create vue-aws-sdk-inv`

[Note: Steps 2 - 4, are not crucial to reproduce issue, but install webpack-bundle-analyzer which provides useful extra info.]

2. In the new project, install webpack-bundle-analyzer. Run: `npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer`
3. Create root file: vue.config.js
4. Add the following code to vue.config.js:

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
  }
};
```

5. As a benchmark, build the project. Run: `npm run build`

At this stage, the project will build (with no console warnings) and webpack-bundle-analyzer will launch (in the browser) showing the file: chunk-vendors..js, at the top of the tree, containing a bunch of other .js files, all of acceptable size.

6. Install AWS Amplify (and by default aws-sdk). Run: `npm i aws-amplify`
7. Open src/components/HelloWorld.vue and add the following under the  tag: `import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";`
8. Build the project. Run: `npm run build`

At this stage, the project will build WITH console warnings regarding the following files being too large:

```
File                                 Size               Gzipped

dist/js/chunk-vendors.013ac3f0.js    3055.78 KiB        550.49 KiB
dist/js/app.fa2a21c4.js              4.67 KiB           1.67 KiB
dist/css/app.53019c4c.css            0.33 KiB           0.23 KiB
```

If installed, webpack-bundle-analyzer should launch (in the browser) showing an inflated: chunk-vendors..js, due to a hefty: aws-sdk.

aws-sdk will include api: .json files and lib: .js files for every AWS service I can think of!

## The attempt to rectify:

1. Navigate to: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/
2. Clear all services.
3. Select just: AWS.CognitoIdentity
4. Download "Minified" aws-sdk-.js
5. Download "Default" aws-sdk-.min.js

[Note: the following are the steps I am guessing I'm getting wrong?...]

6. In the project, search the node_modules directory for aws-sdk.js and aws-sdk.min.js.

They were found in /node_modules/aws-sdk/dist

7. Replace both files with the downloaded files (renaming to aws-sdk.js and aws-sdk.min.js respectively.)
8. Build the project. Run: `npm run build`

Project will build with same console warnings and same massive aws-sdk, as before, containing all the same .js and .json files for a bunch of services that are not actually imported in the application.

## Final pieces of analysis:

1. Remove aws-sdk.js and aws-sdk.min.js from project's: /node_modules/aws-sdk/dist
2. Build the project. Run: `npm run build`

Project is built without even referencing these files.

3. Rename /node_modules/aws-sdk to /node_modules/TEMP_aws-sdk and attempt to build the project.

Build fails, and this proves (I think) that I was at least trying to add the custom versions, of aws-sdk.js and aws-sdk.min.js, somewhere in the correct directory!

## Source Code:

### vue.config.js:

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
  }
};
```

### src/components/HelloWorld.vue:

```
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
```

As said before, any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";` doesn't currently allow for tree shaking according to [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/488).

Reading through several related issues, it appears that:

```js
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
```

is the best you can currently do. I suspect that over time, the AWS team will figure out a way to better separate the internals.

For readers looking for a way to reduce bundle sizes for the `aws-sdk` package, see [this section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk#in-nodejs-1) of the docs.

In my case:

```js
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';
```

cut the bundle size down by quite a lot. That gets it down to ~57k gz to use S3.

---

Also, for anyone using `nuxt` you can just run `nuxt build -a` to get the build analyzer.

Comment: Thank you, David! I now realize I would not have encountered this problem if I had read a [step that covers reducing bundle size](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start#step-4-integrate-into-your-app) in the the [official Amplify Framework docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/). I've learned my lesson for skipping from the more comprehensive React example code straight to the section specifically aimed for Vue!